# Is there an Android or iPhone app for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, iphone, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use)

Is there an Android or iPhone app for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I suggest you match the content of the question with the title.

Answer (score 4):

https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android+app

Answer (score 0):

For Android I don't know. But for iPhone (as you mentioned in the title) there is [MyStacks](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mystacks/id360030953?mt=8). This covers Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User.

Comment: Seems that it only allows browsing, not answering/commenting? I thing a mobile-compatible HTML layout would be sufficient, no need for a separate app.