# Need to know about Android apps

Tags: discussion, stackapps, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there mobile apps for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/are-there-mobile-apps-for-stack-overflow)
>   [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use)

I wanted to know if there are any Android apps for Stack Overflow so that I can access the site from anywhere.

I have googled but found nothing. If anyone has any pointers, please share as I am quite addicted to Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/are-there-mobile-apps-for-stack-overflow

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there an Android or iPhone app for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/), [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/), [Are there mobile apps for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/), and the related questions linked from there.

Comment: There is also: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/is-there-a-android-app-for-stackexchange http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/218/why-dont-we-have-a-dedicated-android-app?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

http://Stackapps.com is the place to look for 3rd-party apps.

It even has an [android tag](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android). There appear to be [8 different Android apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android+app) listed there.